# convert smarty array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, smarty

I have a smarty array

```
$promoFormData  Smarty_Variable Object (3)
                        ->value = Array (1)
                            deliveryDates => Array (3)
                                 0 => Array (2)
                                      startDate => "2013/06/05"
                                      endDate => "2013/06/28"
                                1 => Array (2)
                                      startDate => "2013/07/05"
                                      endDate => "2013/07/28"
                                2 => Array (2)
                                      startDate => "2013/08/05"
                                      endDate => "2013/08/28"
```

I want to use this array deliveryDates as available dates in datepicker.
So trying to convert the above as the following Javascript array

```
var ranges = [ { start: new Date(2013, 06, 05), end: new Date(2013, 06, 28) },
               { start: new Date(2013, 07, 05), end: new Date(2013, 07, 28) },
               { start: new Date(2013, 08, 05), end: new Date(2013, 07, 28) } ];
```

I have tried using below code:

```
 <script>
    var js_array = new Array();
    {{foreach from=$promoFormData.deliveryDates item=array_item key=id}}
        {{foreach from=$array_item item=sub_array_item key=index}}
            js_array['{{$id}}']['{{$index}}'] = '{{$sub_array_item}}';
        {{/foreach}}
    {{/foreach}}

    console.log(js_array);
</scirpt>
```

And I am getting the below error

```
     TypeError: js_array[0] is undefined
     js_array['0']['startDate'] = '2013/06/05';
```

Anyone please guide me to the right way.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. The array literal "works" (be aware that in javascript `new Date(2013, 06, 05)` is 5 **July** 2013). The script you have posted is not javascript. Are you trying to use Smarty on the server to create an array literal for javascript? So is this really just a Smarty question?

Comment: @RobG Yes I am trying to create array literal in javascript using smarty array. Here Iam using smarty to loop through the array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your [Smarty security settings](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl#advanced.features.security) allow it (specifically, it is in `$php_modifiers`), you could use PHP's [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) function:

```
var js_array = {$promoFormData.deliveryDates|json_encode};
```

Since JSON is a strict subset of actual JavaScript object literal syntax, this should give you a valid JS declaration.