# How to assign array from smarty template to javascript and access the same assigned array in javascript in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, smarty

I've an array titled `$all_states` assigned to smarty template as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [state_name] => Alabama
            [abbreviation] => AL
            [created_at] => 1398342353
            [updated_at] => 1398342353
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [state_name] => Alaska
            [abbreviation] => AK
            [created_at] => 1398342353
            [updated_at] => 1398342353
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [state_name] => Arizona
            [abbreviation] => AZ
            [created_at] => 1398342353
            [updated_at] => 1398342353
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [state_name] => Arkansas
            [abbreviation] => AR
            [created_at] => 1398342353
            [updated_at] => 1398342353
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [state_name] => California
            [abbreviation] => CA
            [created_at] => 1398342353
            [updated_at] => 1398342353
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [state_name] => Colorado
            [abbreviation] => CO
            [created_at] => 1398342354
            [updated_at] => 1398342354
        )
)
```

I've a jQuery code on same page as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.prettyPrint() && prettyPrint();

  /*Actually I want to use the values from the above array into below loop*/
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    $('#example28').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
  }

    $('#example28').multiselect({
      includeSelectAllOption: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      maxHeight: 150
    });
  });
```

You can see from the comment in above code that I want to parse the above array in smarty into the javascript for loop. How should I achieve this? I've to acheve this anyhow so is anyone here who can help me in this regard? Thanks in advance. If you still need any more information regarding my issue I can provide you the same.

Comment: The simple answer that worked well for me is at:[http://stackoverflow.com/a/16848431/165164](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16848431/165164)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
window.prettyPrint() && prettyPrint();

var myPhpArray = <?php echo json_encode($all_states); ?>; // <-- HERE'S YOUR ARRAY

/*Actually I want to use the values from the above array into below loop*/
for (var i = 1; i <= myPhpArray.length; i++) {
    $('#example28').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
}

$('#example28').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    maxHeight: 150
});
});
```

Thing is, you can't pass an array from php to js directly.. I don't know much about smarty so see it as a more generic approach of how it's done.