# Converting Multidimensional smary array to Javascript Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, smarty

I have a multi-dimensional  array  named graph in PHP that I sent to smarty.tpl file and I am getting it in tpl in the name of smarty variable graph.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [weight] => 950.500
            [date] => 27
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [weight] => 800.100
            [date] => 31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [weight] => 250.250
            [date] => 03
        )

)
```

Now, I would like to create a multi-dimensional array in javascript in that tpl . How can I do that ?

```
echo json_encode($graph);


$smarty -> assign("graph",$graph);
$smarty -> assign("data_weight",$data_weight);
```

and inside tpl file I am trying to get the array in this format

```
var d1 = [[1,100], [2,110], [3,99],  [4,114]];
```

I have tried this command to convert json object to array

```
var d1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graph));
```

But even that is not working.

Comment: It is not an javascript issue, its related to PHP

Comment: Found the solution??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert smarty array to javascript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847114/convert-smarty-array-to-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and the best way is to send this array from php to javascript in json format... ie,

You can code it as

```
echo json_encode($YOUR_PHP_ARRAY);
```

and when you receive at javascript side.. it always treats json well so you can easily use it directly as it is on client side..

As you shared your json_encode with me... here is the javascript code to read your array.. I used document.write to print it over your page..
and I saved your json which javascript will receive from your php in `var x`

```js
     var x = [{"weight":"950.500","date":"27"},{"weight":"800.100","date":"31"},{"weight":"25‌​0.250","date":"03"}];
     // console.log(x);
    
     for(var i = 0;i<x.length;i++){
      console.log(x[i]);
      document.write("Weight : "+x[i].weight);
      document.write("Date : "+x[i].date);
      document.write("<br/>");
     }
```

Here is how it looks when you run the code snippet..
[image]

And using smarty you can code like

```
var graph = {$graph|json_encode};
```

And get the graph variable which is a javascript variable to be traversed as shown in my snippet.
And for viewing the array structure, you can

```
console.log(graph);
```

and see it in your browser console.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt support . I can understand that we are sending array to smarty using json, but how can I access the result in a variable iln javascript ?

Comment: Oh sure... can you send me the json_encode($array) from your php please.. I ll access it and show you for javascript.. @Sunil

Comment: Thanks , I am getting this as response [{"weight":"950.500","date":"27"},{"weight":"800.100","date":"31"},{"weight":"250.250","date":"03"}]

Comment: if the things go well with this solution.. please mark the answer as correct &or upvote it

Comment: @ Tirthraj Barot    Unfortunately it is not working , please check the updated codes.

Comment: @Sunil did you run the code snippet here? it does traverse through the array pretty well.... If it doesn't, Kindly post the error you are getting , in comment here.... So that i can rectify... I am updating my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: and please correct me if i have added your json to my `x` variable in an improper manner.@Sunil